# Ubuntu: change kernel order

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, kernel

How can I change the boot kernel order in Ubuntu server 13.10?

grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-9e268fa1-53bd-4d32-a3b3-ae07362f89cb' {
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-9e268fa1-53bd-4d32-a3b3-ae07362f89cb' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-12-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-12-generic-advanced-9e268fa1-53bd-4d32-a3b3-ae07362f89cb' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-12-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-12-generic-recovery-9e268fa1-53bd-4d32-a3b3-ae07362f89cb' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.7-030407-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.4.7-030407-generic-advanced-9e268fa1-53bd-4d32-a3b3-ae07362f89cb' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.7-030407-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.4.7-030407-generic-recovery-9e268fa1-53bd-4d32-a3b3-ae07362f89cb' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
```

I want to set the default kernel `menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.4.7-030407-generic'`

In all the docs I've found on google, it's suggested to:
changed `GRUB_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and `update-grub`

but GRUB_DEFAULT doesn't effect `submenu` where my kernel is located.

for example, if I'm selecting `GRUB_DEFAULT=2` than `menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)'` would be chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Submenu Designation Examples](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

The first entry specifies the main menu item (counted from 0 onwards), the second the sub menu item (also counted from 0).